# AngularJS directive renders template twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
angular.module('lawgauge')
    .directive('mainheader', function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          templateUrl:'/angular/templates/header',
        };
});
```

This directive loads page header template, but it renders this twice.
I call it like this:

```
<header class="nclear" mainheader ></header>
```

This is screenshot of problem: https://yadi.sk/i/0HEjsf1uhHYom
What can I do with this problem?

Comment: wat does the template file look like?

Comment: Is there any chance you defined your directive twice in another location?

Comment: It just a html, no matters what file contains - it renders twice anyway.

Comment: I searched in my project and there is no more definitions

Comment: If I put any javascript in template like "alert('hi')" - it fires one time, but html renders twice

Comment: What file does `templateUrl:'/angular/templates/header',` refer to? (What's in it?)

Comment: templateUrl:'/angular/templates/header' is just a plain html like <div>This is header</div>

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code.

Comment: Code is too large for publish here(

Answer (score 1):

I've not found reason of double rendered template by directive, but I fixed it using ng-include instead custom directive:

```
<header class="nclear" ng-include src="'/angular/templates/header'" ></header>
```